# How to find general solution of the equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Will we solve the equation as PDE or ODE? What are the methods of solution?

$x\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}+yw=\frac{1}{1+x^{2y}}$

**My solution:**

it is a linear ODE which is

$w'+\frac{y}{x}w=\frac{1}{x(1+x^{2y})}$. If we use integration factor, we get $d(xu)=\frac{x^y}{x(1+x^{2y})}dx$

But I can' t do the rest of solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Is $w$ a function of $x$ and $y$? Is $y$ a function of $x$?

Comment: There is only one derivative, $\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}$, so the equation can be treated as an ODE with $w$ as the dependent variable and $x$ as the independent variable. Since you have a partial derivative, the constant of integration that you get from solving a first order ODE will be a function of $y$, which is constant with respect to $x$, instead of a plain old constant. EDIT: I'm assuming that $w(x,y)$, with $x$ and $y$ independent.

Comment: **My solution:** 

it is a linear ODE which is 
$w'+\frac{y}{x}w=\frac{1}{x(1+x^{2y})}$. If we use integration factor, we get $d(xu)=\frac{x^y}{x(1+x^{2y})}dx$

But I can' t do the rest of solution. Can you help me?